# Training an AI on a set of Input and Output Values

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I'm new to this whole machine learning thing, and was wondering what the best way to train an AI on 2 lists, one of inputs and one of outputs. After looking on Google, I wasn't able to find a clear solution to my problem. Could anyone write a tutorial / link me to a tutorial that they think is best? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Machine Learning is a very big world. Before to code, you shall know a bit of theory. However, if you want to learn while coding, one fantastic source is https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ, a marvelous youtube channel!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question particularly.
For any model to train in machine learning sci-kit learn library is used. The most basic and fundamental way is to import
train_test_split feature from the sklearn.model_selection i.e

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

In here test_size shows how much percentage od your dataset is used for testing the model you have trained. Random state shows how much randomness you have added in your dataset to improve and ease your model for training.

And for understanding the concepts of machine learning the most lucid tutorial is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/machine_learning_with_python/index.htm. Tutorials Point to the rescue, as always!